# SQL Server - Query help

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

**MEDIA**

```
MediaID     MediaTypeID   Title
---------------------------------------------
100         25            Photo of Anton Oliver
200         25            Photo of Hika Eliot
```

**CAMPAIGNS** (campaigns use media and belong to pools)

```
CampaignID   MediaID   PoolID
----------------------------
1            100       1
2            100       2
3            200       1
```

**CAMPAIGN POOLS**

```
PoolID       PoolName
--------------------
1            Pool1
2            Pool2
3            Pool3
```

Given a specific `campaignID` and `poolID` passed to the query, I want the following select query to determine whether the media belongs to the passed campaign AND/OR Pool

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM media m
<!--- whatever required joins --->
```

So, the resulting recordset would look something like this:

**MediaData**

```
MediaID   MediaTypeID   Title  BelongsToCampaign   BelongsToPool
----------------------------------------------------------------
1         25             xyz       0                   1
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Select MediaID,MediaTypeID,Title,ISNULL(c.CampaignID,0) as  BelongsToCampaign,ISNULL(p.PoolID,0) as  BelongsToPool
From Media m
LEFT OUTER JOIN Campaign c on m.MediaID=c.MediaID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pools p on p.PoolID=c.PoolID
where c.CampaignID=@CampaignID OR p.PoolID=@PoolID
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.MediaID, m.MediaTypeID, m.mediaTitle as Title, c.CampaignID as BelongsToCampaign,     cp.PoolID as belongsToPool
from campaings c, media m,  campaign_pools cp
where (m.mediaid = c.mediaid) and (c.poolId = cp.poolId) and 
(c.campaignID = [your variable] or cp.PoolId = [your other variable])
```

Comment: This is not the standard tsql syntax. I think without specifying the type of join, the comma defaults to an inner join, which doesn't satisfy his requirements. Besides I think he wants 0 for null values, so an isnull statement is required in the select section.

Comment: Don't use the old-style `from campaigns c, media m, ...` JOIN syntax - it's legacy, it's dangerous if you happen to forget a JOIN condition, it's messy because you end up having JOIN conditions and actual WHERE conditions all mixed together in a the WHERE clause - use the **ANSI JOIN** syntax (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) instead!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your spec you want the resultset to return all media or only certain subsets (as per @BizApps's answer) -- posting more than two rows of sample data might help here ;)

The following unions the four possible subsets: remove or comment out the ones you don't need. I trust you can see where CTEs could be used to reduce repetition in code:

```
SELECT m.*, t.BelongsToCampaign, t.BelongsToPool
  FROM (
        -- Campaign INTERSECT Pool
        SELECT c.MediaID, 1 AS BelongsToCampaign, 1 AS BelongsToPool
          FROM CAMPAIGNS AS c
         WHERE c.CampaignID = @CampaignID
        INTERSECT 
        SELECT MediaID, 1, 1
          FROM CAMPAIGN_POOLS AS p JOIN CAMPAIGNS AS c ON p.PoolID = c.PoolID
         WHERE p.PoolID = @PoolID

        -- Campaign EXCEPT Pool
        UNION
        SELECT c.MediaID, 1, 0
          FROM CAMPAIGNS AS c
         WHERE c.CampaignID = @CampaignID
        EXCEPT 
        SELECT MediaID, 1, 0
          FROM CAMPAIGN_POOLS AS p JOIN CAMPAIGNS AS c ON p.PoolID = c.PoolID
         WHERE p.PoolID = @PoolID

        -- Pool EXCEPT Campaign
        UNION
        SELECT MediaID, 0, 1
          FROM CAMPAIGN_POOLS AS p JOIN CAMPAIGNS AS c ON p.PoolID = c.PoolID
         WHERE p.PoolID = @PoolID
        EXCEPT 
        SELECT c.MediaID, 0, 1
          FROM CAMPAIGNS AS c
         WHERE c.CampaignID = @CampaignID

        -- Media in neither Pool nor Campaign
        UNION
        SELECT m.MediaID, 0, 0
          FROM MEDIA AS m
        EXCEPT 
        SELECT c.MediaID, 0, 1
          FROM CAMPAIGNS AS c
         WHERE c.CampaignID = @CampaignID
        EXCEPT 
        SELECT MediaID, 1, 0
          FROM CAMPAIGN_POOLS AS p JOIN CAMPAIGNS AS c ON p.PoolID = c.PoolID             
         WHERE p.PoolID = @PoolID
       ) AS t 
       JOIN MEDIA AS m ON m.MediaID = t.MediaID;
```